# Upgrading from Helm stable/cert-manager to jetstack/cert-manager

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, lets-encrypt, azure-aks, cert-manager

We have a production AKS cluster that has a `stable/cert-manager` helm chart installed to allow using Let's Encrypt certificates. The current version installed is `cert-manager-v0.6.0` in the `kube-system` namespace.

Let's Encrypt is to stop support for traffic from cert-manager pre 8.0 version from 1st of November 2019.

I would like to upgrade but the latest available `stable` chart version is `v0.6.7`. Seems like the way to go is to switch to `jetstack/cert-manager`.

How do I best approach this? Shall I uninstall the current `stable/cert-manager` chart and install from scratch with the `jetstack/cert-manager`? Any resource on how to tackle this without downtime in production would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide any more details.

Comment: It seems you cannot upgrade the stable/cert-manager to jetstack/cert-manager through helm without downtime. You need to uninstall the old one and install the new one. Take a look at the example of [helm upgrade](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrading.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone asking the same question, I have tried to perform clean install on my test cluster and this seemed to work fairly smoothly. I have found what the name of my the helm release was by running `helm list`

then I have performed the following steps:

**1.Backup**:

```
kubectl get -o yaml \
   --all-namespaces \
   issuer,clusterissuer,certificates,orders,challenges > cert-manager-backup.yaml
```

[Source](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/tasks/backup-restore-crds.html)

**2.Delete**:

```
# Uninstall the Helm chart
helm delete --purge <your release name here>

# Ensure the cert-manager CustomResourceDefinition resources do not exist:
kubectl delete crd \
    certificates.certmanager.k8s.io \
    issuers.certmanager.k8s.io \
    clusterissuers.certmanager.k8s.io
```

described in step 2 [here](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/tasks/upgrading/upgrading-0.5-0.6.html)

**3.Install a fresh jetstack version**:

```
# Install the CustomResourceDefinition resources separately
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetstack/cert-manager/release-0.9/deploy/manifests/00-crds.yaml

# Create the namespace for cert-manager
kubectl create namespace cert-manager

# Label the cert-manager namespace to disable resource validation
kubectl label namespace cert-manager certmanager.k8s.io/disable-validation=true

# Add the Jetstack Helm repository
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io

# Update your local Helm chart repository cache
helm repo update

# Install the cert-manager Helm chart
helm install --name <your release name here> --namespace cert-manager --version v0.9.1 jetstack/cert-manager
```

described [here](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/getting-started/install/kubernetes.html#installing-with-helm)

**4.Restore**:

I have tried running

```
kubectl apply -f cert-manager-backup.yaml
```

as described [here](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/tasks/backup-restore-crds.html#restoring) but this step actually didn't fully work for me. The Issuers were created (self signed and CA) but I could not re-create the `Certificates` and `ClusterIssuer`. These were the errors I have received:

```
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "clusterissuers.admission.certmanager.k8s.io": the server is currently unable to handle the request
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "certificates.admission.certmanager.k8s.io": the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

I had my original `yaml` files and was able to create the `ClusterIssuer` and `Certificate` by applying them

Comment: Following those [instructions](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/10869#issuecomment-473567532) work for you? Or do you have any other problems. In addition the question is it would be better to upgrade to 0.7.0 jetstack/cert-manager and than following upgrade section?

Comment: @Hanx the steps I described were the only once I have taken. As step 2 deletes the cert-manager I thought I might as well go straight to version 0.9

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the above works.  (@RVid answer)

Though, I've upgraded 0.5.0 to 0.9.1 and had to create a separate namespace to have 'no-downtime' upgrade.

```
#1 delete old CRDs
kubectl delete crd \
    certificates.certmanager.k8s.io \
    issuers.certmanager.k8s.io \
    clusterissuers.certmanager.k8s.io

#2 create SEPARATE namespace
$ kubectl create namespace cert-manager-new

#3 install new CRDs that corresponds to the new version of cert-manager

$ kubectl apply \
    -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetstack/cert-manager/<VERSION>/deploy/manifests/00-crds.yaml


#4 ensure the NEW namespace has an additional label on it in order for the deployment to succeed
$ kubectl label namespace cert-manager-new certmanager.k8s.io/disable-validation="true"

#5 copy secrets to cert-manager-new namespace (For DNS, HTTP and Let's Encrypt account)

## Install the cert-manager helm chart
#  jetstack/cert-manager
$ helm install --name cert-manager-new --namespace cert-manager-new jetstack/cert-manager --values <your values file>

#6 apply ClusterIssuer with kubectl apply -f <file.yaml> 
Use config from: https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/reference/issuers.html
```

The new instance of the cert manager will start synchronizing all the certificates you have without destroying the secrets.
Eventually, all the certs will get renewed with new cert-manager.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the overview! I was just wondering if its necessary to do this? I was wondering about upgrading in place (leaving the issuers running as normal). Would this potentially cause an outage for our services?

Comment: Also! Did you just delete the old helm deployment, and how long did it take to synchronize? Thank you!

Comment: Just to note that I follow this approach and it worked ok for me!