# No downtime upgrade of jetstack cert-manager in Kubernetes using Helm

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade, cert-manager

We need to upgrade our cert-manager (v 0.5.0) to the latest one (currently 0.10.0) because of the support end from Let's Encrypt on November 1st 2019.

I have found following answer by @bzumby on how to upgrade cert-manager, where he describe a no-downtime upgrade sequence for cert-manager: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57807983/12115618

From the answer, a new cert-manager chart is installed to the cluster in a separate namespace, in order for the new cert manager to start syncing all the certificates already in place.

But nothing is mentioned about what to do with the previous cert-manager installation.

Am I correct in assuming that the  old cert-manager helm chart (including the associated namespace) needs to be deleted AFTER the steps described in the answer? Is there any additional actions that need to be taken?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a no downtime upgrade? It’s a controller, having it be down for a minute or two is not generally a problem.

Comment: Hey! I'm also in the same position, so interested in this. My understanding is that we'd be fine by just upgrading in place without new namespace etc. but then I read this blog post and wasn't sure! Did you do this upgrade Louis - did you push ahead by upgrading in place?